# How to make Terminator open new tab with my default layout

Tags: terminator

In Terminator, I have a 3-split layout that I have set as the default layout as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout). But when I open a new tab, it still opens with just a single terminal, not the 3-split layout I want.

How to make Terminator open all new tabs with my default layout?

Note: The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391353/how-to-set-default-layout-profile-for-terminator-for-tabs-on-start) does not work for layouts.

Comment: im having the same problem. if i find anything i'll be sure to come back